# how can i fill textbox on FORM4 from FORM7

Tags: vb.net

i want when double click txtLocalEastDdfFrom on FORM4(FIBER_OPTIC) it returne value from FORM7(DDF_FROM) and fill txtLocalEastDdfFrom. this action work on FORM1 and FORM5,but dont work on FORM4 and FORM7.
please help me.

```
("FORM7=DDF_FROM")
Public Class DDF_FROM
    Private Sub btnApplay_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnApplay.Click
        FIBER_OPTIC.txtLocalEastDdfFrom.Text = CombDdfFromRow.Text & CombDdfFromBay.Text & "-" & CombDdfFromShelf.Text & "-" & CombDdfFromNumber.Text
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

txtLocalEastDdfFrom IS ON ("FORM4=FIBER_OPTIC")

```
 Private Sub txtLocalEastDdfFrom_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtLocalEastDdfFrom.DoubleClick
      Dim EastddfAdd As New DDF_FROM
      EastddfAdd.Show()
 End Sub
```

Comment: There really isn't enough information here to understand what's going on. How are references being set up between the forms? What actually happens? an exception? nothing? As an aside, don't use lots of `&` to join strings. it's inefficient. Use `String.Format("{0}{1} - {2}...", CombDdfFromRow.Text, CombDdfFromBay.Text, CombDdfFromShelf.Text, ...)`

Comment: Format isn't matter ,this is work on form1 and form5.in this case it returne blank.

Comment: I didn't say it was the problem, just that it's inefficient

Answer (score 0):

Don't use New Form just to display the form use instead it's actual form name to display like

Form4.Show()

Then...

Form4.TextBox1.Text = Form7.TextBox1.Text

Comment: Or the Form4 is not yet .Show() ?